# Playing Background sound metro app

Tags: c#, audio, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to play sound in the background but it only plays in the foreground when I alt tab stops playing...

```
snd = new MediaElement();
snd.AudioCategory = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.AudioCategory.BackgroundCapableMedia;
StorageFolder folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("hey.mp3");
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
snd.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
snd.Play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's sample for [Background Audio in WinRT with C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-in-WinRT-344bcf4d) from MSDN